# Services that require CA certificates are not available in the Android MSTeams app

Tags: javascript, android, microsoft-teams, ca, microsoft-graph-teams

We are developing an app for Teams.
Access to some of the client services that we use is only possible if you have installed some CA certificates.

With the specific CA certificates installed on PCs, the app works fine with both the desktop and the web versions of MS Teams.
We can access these services using our application through MS Teams.

If we try to reach the customer services using the Android version of the MS Team app, we get the same error as if we do not install the CA certificates.
But the CA certificates are installed correctly, because the web version (with desktop mode via Chrome browser) works fine for Android devices (and does not work without CA certificates installed on Android).

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem?
And how you can check whether the certificate is applied when trying to get access to specific server/service through MS Teams?

Comment: Hi @VaruVaru, we are checking internally with engineering team, will update to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

We have gone through your question and found that there is a similar question request raised by another user and our engineering team is working on it.
Could you please have a look on this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/services-that-require-ca-certificates-are-not-available-in-the/m-p/2105324#M2562) to track your question.